# When deactivated virtual environment, why it still looking for pyvenv.cfg?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyvenv

Need some help here, I have used virtual environment for doing some of my projects, when deactivated the virtual environemnt, and restart the terminal, it said that No pyvenv.cfg file.

At Windows terminal:

```
C:\Users\Morris>python
No pyvenv.cfg file
```

How can I tell the system no need to look for pyvenv.cfg when it is not in virtual environment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it by just uninstall the python, as well delete all the app data. And then reinstall back the python.

```
C:\Users\Morris>python

Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```